# Discord Bot Python message logs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, chatbot

**Hi so I need to create a discord bot in python that stores a specific users sent messages in a seperate channels. Basically like message logs but its just for one user and every message they sent deleted or not** If anyone could show me how to do that it would mean ALOT

Comment: This is not a code writing service, you are expected to attempt your goal and show it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: StackOverflow is a forum to help users *debug* code or get clarity or related topics given that they provide an attempt and show their code (the official Community Comment above should be enough to reflect this as well as the 3 downvotes you have). Considering you are a *very* new member consider [Taking the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and view [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is a simple "I don't know how to do X, please show me how" where as "I'm having trouble doing X, here's what I have so far. Where is my mistake?" is better.

Comment: @Elitezen direct me where it shows its REQUIRED in your question to have code thats already been made.

Comment: From *How to ask* "*Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*" while it's not *required* it greatly *helps us help you*

Comment: It says its not required. Proving my point that users have done it before and theirs nothing wrong with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with Elitezen's comment, the answer is quite simple.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=<YOUR PREFIX>)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == <ID OF USER>:
        with open("log.txt","a") as f:
            f.write(message.content + "\n")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thank you but Im just asking a question